# getting url parameters from iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to pass variables into an iframe but they don't seem to be working.

**Source html**

```
<iframe src="iframe_test_inner.html?id=zzz" width="800" height="300"></iframe>
```

**iframe javascript**

```
var url = window.location.href;
console.log(url);
```

typing the url with parameters into the browser the console shows the full string; however, using the iframe from a source HTML all the parameters are stripped out. Not sure what i'm missing, did they change it so this doesn't work anymore? All references and examples i've found are pre 2012.

Comment: Does your iframe contents originate from the same domain? Take a look at the Cross-Origin Sharing if they do not.

Comment: If they are on the same domain, there's nothing in the code you've posted that should cause parameters to be stripped. [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nzybnhur/)

Comment: yes they are on different domains. Trying to get cookies to share between the domains (same IP) nothing seems to reliably work and have to use javascript because they don't want to install PHP or another server side language. Because they are on the same IP i tried using that to set the cookie but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can't do it. Plain and simple. Once they are on different domains you cannot alter the contents of it due to security concerns. Here's a link to Mozilla's developer site that discusses it a bit more. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy